# My character is stuck in T post after editing base mesh and is no longer parented to armature, the armature still moves but the character wont follow

Tags: animation, armature

I had my character mesh animating with the bones how I wanted until I edited the mesh of the character. Now my character is stuck in T pose. [image]

Comment: Either the armature modifier is gone or the vertex groups are.

Comment: i selected every bone in pose mode then reset position, location, and scale, then reparented using automatic weights in object mode, but in the future is there anything else i can do?

Comment: the whole first step to clear the pose probably wasn’t necessary.

Comment: what should i have donnne? @TheLabCat

Comment: just reparented to the armature with automatic weights.